# How big is too big to fly on American Airlines?

Tags: seating, american-airlines

I am travelling to New York in November with American Airlines and I'm freaking out over whether I will be able to fit in the seat. I am a UK size 22/24 bottom and 20 top.

Has anyone else flown with this airline and can let me know?

Comment: Airline specific information: https://www.cheapair.com/blog/travel-tips/airline-policies-for-overweight-passengers-traveling-this-summer/